# How to get specific state applying $e^{-i\phi \sigma_2/2}$ to $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$?

Tags: mathematics, pauli-gates

I try to solve problems from [Problems in Quantum Computing](http://issc.uj.ac.za/downloads/problems/QCProblems.pdf).

I stuck with problem #3:

[image]

I do the following:

Because:
$$ \sigma_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i\\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then: 
$$ -i \frac{\phi}{2}\sigma_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\frac{\phi}{2}\\
\frac{\phi}{2} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\exp\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\frac{\phi}{2}\\
\frac{\phi}{2} & 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \exp(-\frac{\phi}{2})\\
\exp(\frac{\phi}{2}) & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

If I multiply the result of the last calculation with $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$ I can't get $\psi_1(\phi)$ or $\psi_2(\phi)$. I get some unnormalised state like:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
\exp(\frac{\phi}{2}) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Does it mean that the definition of the problem is not correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is computing exponent of matrix; use the formula

$$\exp(i\theta\sigma_2)=\cos(\theta)\cdot I+i\cdot \sin(\theta)\cdot\sigma_2$$

Comment: I haven't known about this "hack". Could you suggest a site where I can read about it?

Comment: This "hack" should be in any good QM or Quantum Information course; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector); I substituted $\hat{n}=(0,1,0)$

Comment: This is an application of a matrix function definition. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

A matrix function $f(A)$ for normal matrix $A$ is defined as follows
\begin{equation}
f(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\lambda_i)v_iv_i^T
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_{i}$ is an eigenvalue and $v_{i}$ is coresponding eigenvector (note: transposed vector $v_{i}$ is a row vector).

**In your case:** $f(A) = \mathrm{e}^A$ and $A = -i\frac{\phi}{2}\sigma_{2}$.

Comment: +1, though a reference stating the formula along with a proof would be appreciated.

Comment: For more information see Nielsen and Chuang, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information, pg. 75 (chapter 2.1.8 - Operator functions)

Comment: @Martin, thanks for your note. One quick question, in this case what is ?

Comment: please use comments for additional questions. $v_{i}$ is *ith* eigenvector of matrix $A$.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3784)